# In Linux device driver what callback gets called during system shutdown

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, shutdown, suspend

I would like to know what callback gets called in Linux device drivers when issuing `poweroff` from user space. The driver is built as external module.
For suspend / resume we have `struct dev_pm_ops` methods.
Is there any method/callback that could be registered for getting called when issuing `poweroff`/`shutdown` command from user space?

Comment: Have you tried to read the code? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/core.c#L4479 Also there is a global notifier on reboot and shutdown. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/reboot.c